# Which files are sent to the Firebase cloud functions environment when you deploy the functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have the following structure inside my `functions` folder for my Firebase app.

```
functions
  > node_modules      // INSTALLED NODE MODULES
  > distApp           // REACT APP FILES TRANSPILED WITH BABEL
      App.js
      index.html
  > distFunctions     // FUNCTION FILES TRANSPILED WITH BABEL
      function1.js    // SOME OF THEM USE FILES FROM 'distApp' FOLDER
      function2.js
  > src               // FUNCTION FILES WRITTEN IN ES6+
      function1.js
      function2.js
indexES6.js           // CLOUD FUNCTIONS index.js WRITTEN IN ES6+
index.js              // CLOUD FUNCTIONS index.js TRANSPILED WITH BABEL
package.json
```

**QUESTION**

I would like to understand what happend when I deploy my `index.js` file.

- What files are going to be available inside my `Node.js` environment? Do all files inside my `functions` folder (and subfolders) are going to be sent to my `Node.js` environment?
- What if none of my functions use (require) a file named `someFile.xxx`. But that file is sitting there inside of one of my `functions` subfolders. Is it going to be sent to the Cloud Functions environment?
- The `node_modules` folder is ignored during the deployment and packages are installed inside the Node.js environment in the Cloud. Am I right?

**NOTE:** This `functions` folder lives inside my Firebase project root folder, where I have a `firebase.json` file and everything else needed for deployment.

**PS:** I know it's not best practice to ask more than one question here on SO, but they're all related to the main question: **"Exactly which files and folders are deployed to the cloud functions environment when you run `firebase deploy --only functions` "**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything from your functions folder gets deployed, except node_modules.  It doesn't matter what your index.js contains.

Cloud Functions will reconstitute your node_modules folder on the backend by running `npm install`.  So, the contents of your package.json matters a lot.

In the end, Cloud Functions builds a docker image and puts all those files and modules from your functions folder into it, and it will all be available when your function executes.